# Can I make a scrollbar start after the container's padding?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a horizontal scroll container like in the image below. It has some horizontal padding which causes the scrollbar to start too far on the left. It needs the padding so that the shadows below the cards don't get cut off by the container.

[image: horizontal scroll container current]

I'd like to keep the padding and make the scrollbar start where the first card starts like this:

[image: horizontal scroll container desired]

Here's the code for the general layouts (also in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Susccy/pen/porNoNQ)):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.horizontal-padding {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.content {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<p>Current layout with padding where scrollbar starts too far on the left:</p>
<div class="container horizontal-padding">
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
</div>

<p>Layout without padding where scrollbar starts nicely with the content but shadows are cut off:</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
  <div class="content">Sample Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This can be done by using a extra container on the outside with full screen width and padding a you needed

Comment: @Rana I don't know how a wrapping container helps here unfortunately, can you create an example?

Answer (score 0):

One of the posibilities is **adding padding** on the containers and see how much would you want to put in

or another option is to **make a box or container** new that you adapt it with your preferences

Also another option is using the **border** property of the same color that the backgounrd

Comment: Sorry I don't understand any of your suggestions.